# How to check my total memory, used memory and free memory from top command?

Tags: top

How to check my total memory, used memory and free memory according to this result?
[image]

free -m

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   

available
Mem:         128658        4759       30367        3883       93531      119404
Swap:          8191         244        7947

02:40:01 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
02:50:01 PM  31184260 100561996     76.33   2250516  85014564  20484900     14.62  29845888  61199724       568
03:00:01 PM  31103512 100642744     76.39   2250612  85021892  20433296     14.58  29926724  61203688       344
03:10:01 PM  31192884 100553372     76.32   2250716  85041488  20080652     14.33  29825276  61216504      1148
03:20:01 PM  31159024 100587232     76.35   2250784  85044132  20455336     14.60  29859924  61214376       416
03:30:01 PM  31041176 100705080     76.44   2250860  85049904  20569624     14.68  29977032  61215628       376
03:40:01 PM  31033884 100712372     76.44   2250940  85053796  20253364     14.45  29980684  61218348       108
03:50:01 PM  30990324 100755932     76.48   2251008  85057576  21841892     15.59  30015132  61217244       324
04:00:01 PM  30990848 100755408     76.48   2251088  85077056  20454580     14.60  30018776  61225684       820
Average:     31285793 100460463     76.25   2246895  84940657  20181266     14.40  29716343  61248837       435
```

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid posting pictures of text. They can be hard or impossible to read and have other downsides.

Memory sizes are conveniently labeled "total", "free" and "used", so I am a bit at a loss to understand why you ask this question. The unit is also shown, KiB, or Kibibytes, i.e. 1024 bytes. The first line is about RAM; around 30GB of your RAM is free and over 4GB used. Over 90GB are currently used to cache disk blocks. The second line shows you how much swap space is currently in use (very little in your case).

Your total RAM is too large to be shown in KiB, thus top puts a plus sign next to the figure. My guess is that you have 128GB, but to be certain, I suggest you change the unit to the next higher value (MiB) by typing `E`.

top has an excellent manual page. I suggest you study it.

To see only memory figures, I recommend the `free` command.

Comment: I have attached free and sar -r result. Which should I refer? 75% memory usage? @berndbausch

Comment: They look the same. Both report around 30GB free, which corresponds to 25%.

Comment: Will the usage of memory too high? 70% used. @bernbaush

Comment: I would say you are wasting 30%. Normally, Linux tends to maximize memory usage, but your workload doesn't permit it to use more.

Comment: How to make it use 100% of memory. @berndbausch

Comment: Run more applications or cause more file IO. The latter will be hard, because the buffer cache occupies already 80 to 90 GB.